# Nuget api issue

Tags: c#, nuget

I need to automatically collect the information from the nuget packages of a series of projects. For this purpose I use the API that miscrosoft makes available.

Making the call:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3/epplus/index.json

I get the most recent version: v.4.5.3.1 while on the nuget website it is: v. 5.1.2.

To make the call I use the following code:

```
static void GetNuGetIndex(Model.Package package)
    {
        string uri = "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3/" + package.Name.ToLower() + "/index.json";

        string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(uri);
        var packageIndex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONModel.NuGetPackageIndex>(json);
        int packageIndexItemCounter = 0;
        if (packageIndex.Items.Count > 0)
            foreach (var packageItem in packageIndex.Items)
            {
                packageIndexItemCounter++;
                List<JSONModel.NuGetPackageItem> items = packageItem.Items;

                if (packageItem.Items == null)
                {
                    string lookupjson = new WebClient().DownloadString(packageItem.LookupUrl);
                    items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONModel.NuGetPackageItems>(lookupjson).Items;
                }

                GetNuGetItems(package, items, package.Name, package.Version, (packageIndexItemCounter.Equals(packageIndex.Items.Count) ? packageItem.Upper : "" ));
            }
    }
```

Can anyone give me an explanation of why I have this problem and how can it be solved?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is because this endpoint has been discontinued.

Consulting to the service index api, available at: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json ([DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/service-index)) you can see that the address you are using is not returned.

When consulting the endpoint https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/epplus/index.json provided by the index api, the "upper" field will now return the most current version

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I looked [here](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json), which suggests you need a different query to return packages:

[https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/epplus/index.json](https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/epplus/index.json)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 0):

As Kelvin mentioned, that registration hive has been discontinued. I would recommend using the NuGet client SDK to interact with the NuGet API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk#list-package-versions

If you still would like to use the NuGet APIs directly, I recommend reading through the following resources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/service-index
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/registration-base-url-resource

TLDR: You have to "discover" the latest location of the registration endpoint using the V3 Service Index API at `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`.